# Load Balancer + Autoscaling + Mysql on EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb, autoscaling

We have an EC2 instance which is a website, which uses a mysql database which is on another EC2 instance in the same region. In mysql, we have provided restricted access based on server elastic IP to prevent intrusion.
Now, we have decided to install ELB on this server. The ELB part actually works fine, but when auto-scaling spins up a new instance, it has a random public IP address, hence cannot be added to mysql's exceptions.
I tried adding ELB dns(A Name) to mysql for providing access, but it is still not working. The ELB works, Auto scaling spins up a new instance, but the website shows error due to not-connected to database.

How can I correct this?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sw development, this is pure operational stuff. DBAs or sysadmins would be in a lot better position to answer this question, than sw developers.

Comment: Why not have them connect with username, password, where that username has an entry in the grants as `host` wildcard `%` ? Or is it an EC2 Security Group issue (the firewall). A peek at `select user,host from mysql.user` will shed light on how your main server is connecting. Presumably it is thru `localhost`

Answer (score 4):

Rather than restricting access via IP addresses, use **Security Groups**:

- Create a security group (eg `App-SG`) and associate it with any instance that is permitted to communicate with the MySQL server
- Create a security group for the MySQL instance (eg call it `SQL-SG`) and permit **Inbound** connections from `App-SG`

This way, only machines with the `App-SG` will be allowed to communicate with the MySQL instance. When **Auto Scaling** launches new instances that are associated with the `App-SG`, they will also be able to communicate with MySQL.

You should avoid hard-coded IP addresses as much as possible (as in... never use them!).

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be a great idea. But now we have a problem, that we have already used public IP of the DB instance in our code at various locations, and correcting that would be a error prone task. As Security groups only allow access thourh private ip or public dns, we dont know what to do.

Comment: If your database is in the same VPC as your application servers, the application servers should **not** access the database via a Public IP address. This causes the traffic to go out of the VPC (through the Internet Gateway), then back in again, which incurs a cost of 1c/GB of traffic. Instead, you should refer to the database via a DNS name that resolves to the Private IP of the database. This use of **Security Groups** as recommended above and also lets you change the Private IP address of the database in case you need to launch it on another instance (eg in a different AZ/subnet).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of restriciting your database access by IP, consider restricting by subnet.

You will have a public subent (webserver and ELB are there) and a private one (database server is there)
Computers in a public subnet is accessible to everyone in internet, computers in a private subnet is available to only computers in a public subnet.

More information about such configuration is here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html

In order to manage your database server, you can setup a bastion host:
http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2ZWDW1QA6D62Y/Controlling-Network-Access-to-EC2-Instances-Using-a-Bastion-Server

Comment: I have already tried subnets, as I thought of this before. but the issue is now the instances are already running, I cannot find any way to change the subnets of these instances. Otherwise this is a very good solution.